# How to change calendar view within in my app

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, calendar

I am new to Windows development, I am developing an app for Windows phone 8. In that app I have integrated WPcontrol and used the calendar tool. Now I want to change the style and view of the calendar. I edited the template for changing the style.

But I can able to change little bit of that. So if there is anyway to change the full calendar view, then please help me out.

EDIT:

I want to change the date view, display calendar color, Foreground color for the date and the alignment.

Comment: Which Calender you are using? I mean the Windows Phone toolkit or any other 3rd part tool?

Comment: I am using Windows Phone Controls to view the calendar

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone Toolkit is open source and you can download the source code from their Codeplex repository: http://phone.codeplex.com/. This means that you can change everything you like, compile the code and then link those libraries instead of the NuGet package.

Since you haven't described what you wish to change, it is hard to tell you *how* to change it exactly. If you edit your post and explain what you want to do, we can probably tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

He ment the other WPControl package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPControls/1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page for wp8 calendar

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278077%28v=vs.95%29.aspx